# How do I retrieve the values of a single column from a database table?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have a table where I am trying to capture all the values in one column across many rows with a matching identifier. For example my query is similar to:

```
SELECT 
   prevHours 
FROM 
   submissions 
WHERE
  projectCat='Capacity'
```

I am then trying to pass all of the values in prevHours into a single array that I can perform operations on.

Comment: -1 for lack of research and understand how SO works.  This is for specific concerns with your code not "show me how to do something"

Comment: Once you do your research and find out how to execute the query, the easiest way to get to an array from an unknown number of values is to create an empty `List<T>`, keep adding to it as long as needed, then when you're done, call `ToArray()` on that list to get your array.

Comment: Thank you I saw that right after I made the edit. I have made a new edit claiming my indexing is out of range. Any idea on this one?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to work with a list of values from the database is to use a `List<T>`; the code is similar to what you have now, see below.

The code is quite simple:

```
var container = new List<int>();
var dbConnection = "...";
var query = "SELECT [prevHours] FROM [submissions] WHERE [projCat] = @Value";
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
     connection.Open(); 
     command.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar, max).Value = "Capacity";    
     using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         while(reader.Read())
         {
              if(reader["prevHours"] != DBNull.Value)
                   container.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["prevHours"]));
         }
}
```

Additionally, if you are not using the list for further processing, you could use ExecuteScalar and a query of the form

```
SELECT SUM(prevHours) FROM submissions WHERE projCat = @Value
```

for similar results using `command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

I write a function to return a database table:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(SqlConnection conn, string cmdText,
            params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }`
```